# Is changing the reference of a list and reading from it at the same time threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I've implemented this model to avoid locks where I'm trying to fully replace the contents of a list, while reading from it.

Reference assignment is an atomic operation, but I don't really understand what happens if a read/iteration on the list is in progress while the reference is changed. Is this implementation correct?

```
 public class Cache 
 {     
       IList<CacheEntry> cache = new List<CacheEntry>();

       // this method gets called frequently
       public CacheEntry GetForCompany(string companyId)
       { 
            return this.cache.Where(c => c.id == companyId).FirstOrDefault();
       }

       // this method gets called every 5 minutes 
       public void OnUpdate(IEnumerable<CacheEntry> updatedCache) 
       {  
              this.cache = updatedCache.ToList();
       }
 }
```

Are the any issues or race conditions with the code above?

Comment: If your *real* `GetForCompany` method refers to `this.cache` more than once, then yes there is a race condition, and you should make a copy of the reference at the start of the method. Otherwise, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its thread safe in the sense than nothing will actually break or fail but, Linq being lazy, if the `Where` clause is materialized a considerable time later than the call to `GetForCompany` you can get very stale results because the query will return the results of the dated cache, even if the cache has been updated in the mean time.

Comment: Note that it's probably not really a `Where`, since the method returns `CacheEntry` and is called `GetForCompany`. It's probably actually a `FirstOrDefault` which wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, If the query is immediately materialized there is nothing that can really go wrong in the provided example.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the any issues or race conditions with the code above?

It might result in something similar to phantom read. So the answer will be `PhantomRead.BelongsTo(RaceCondition)`

I will explain it in low level pointer way even though you can't access it in c#

after the call OnUpdate this.cache pointer will be pointing to a memory address lets say `0x4`

Then you called `GetForCompany`. The .`Where` call will store the current address of `this.cache` which is `0x4`

Then you called `OnUpdate` again and `this.cache` became `0x100`

When the Where clause enumerate thru the list it will still be looking at the list located at `0x4`. Which means there are actually two sets of list in the memory at that time. The one stored in linq is `0x4` and the new one is `0x100`.

Enumerating thru `0x4` will not give you any trouble since that list is not modified at all